# I am running tar xzvfredhawk-yum-1.8.4-el6-i686.tar.gz and the terminal freezes.

Tags: tar, redhawksdr

I am new to CentOS6 as well as Redhawksdr, and I am trying to run the tar xzvfredhawk-yum-1.8.4-el6-i686.tar.gz instruction on page 24, section 2.3 and my terminal freezes.  Anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Please be more specific. page 24, section 2.3 of what?

Comment: Do you actually have a space between `tar xzvf` and `redhawk-yum-[...]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if yum is being locked by something else (though an error should be produced if this were the case):

```
ps aux | grep yum
```

If something else is locking yum, try killing it.

Also, take a look at your repositories in /etc/yum.repos.d.  Are there any IP addresses in there that might cause a timeout?  Try pinging any IPs that are in there: if you can't ping, remove them from /etc/yum.repos.d (do this by saving the file off somewhere else).

If neither of those work, please post the exact syntax you are using.  If yum is waiting on an input, it will freeze (e.g., if the answer to David Duncan's question is "no", that would be your problem).

user2062950: I am assuming user2643765 is referring to section 2.3 of the REDHAWK user manual.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

go to the location where the tar file is present, then run the following command:

```
tar xzvf redhawk-yum-1.8.4-el6-i686.tar.gz -C target_location
```